# Como carregar uma biblioteca de C em C#?

Tags: c#

Tenho um arquivo de extensão ***lib***, feito em C, que preciso usar em uma aplicação que foi programada em C#. Ao procurar pelo assunto, li sobre *wrappers*, mas não entendi muito bem. Há alguma maneira de usar essa biblioteca com os recursos da linguagem de minha aplicação?

Answer (score 1):

Siga os passos a seguir:

1. Faça uma DLL que serve como um wrapper para sua .lib. Essa DLL é escrita em C ou C++ e deve expor cada função da biblioteca .lib.
2. Chame cada função do wrapper construído no passo 1, através de seu aplicativo em C#.

Esse [blog](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2008/02/16/net-to-c-bridge/) explica como fazer isso detalhadamente.

Answer (score 0):

Como disse o @EduardoFernandes, a única maneira é usando uma DLL. Porém você tem que seguir outros passos. Suponhamos que você fez download do MinGW (ou TDM) GCC para Windows. Crie o arquivo em C++:

```
#ifdef BUILDING_DLL
#define __DLL__ __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define __DLL__ __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

//Totalmente necessário (não sei por que, mas sei que funções em C++ causam crash). Só com wrappers você pode usar classes e outras coisas de C++ em sua aplicação C#.
extern "C"
{
    /* coloque as funções aqui. Sempre use o seu prefixo __DLL__ (os nomes que eu escrevi são como FOO e BAR, pode escolher o que você quiser. */
    int __DLL__ func() { return 0; }
}
```

Compile com o *g++* do GNU GCC:
`g++ -c -DBUILDING_DLL -LC:\CaminhodaLib -lSuaLibParaLinkar arquivo_dll.cpp -o arquivo_dll.o`

-D especifica nosso *preprocessor*, -c especifica o uso para gerar um arquivo não executável e -o é o nome do arquivo de saída. Logo após um arquivo `.o` para *anexar* em aplicações ou ser compilado. Depois prossiga com o seguinte comando:
`g++ -shared arquivo_dll.o -o sua_dll.dll -mwindows --out-implib`. -shared especifica para gerar uma dll, -mwindows é necessário (claro, C#...), --out-implib significa "compilar para uma biblioteca de implementação externa", que acho que é o mais lógico a se fazer.

Quando for usar em sua aplicação, utilize-o da seguinte maneira:

```
[DllImport("sua_dll.dll")]
public class Implementacao
{
    public extern int func();
    public void uso_da_dll()
    {
        func();
    }
}
```

É bom lembrar que isso não é válido para DLLs que têm classes em C++. É necessário que você use alguma ferramenta para isso. Uma que eu conheço é a [PInvoke Interop SDK](http://www.xinterop.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Algumas dicas que podem ajudar.
Para montar a assinatura de interop de módulos escritos em C/C++ você pode utilizar esta ferramenta: [PInvoke Interop Assistant](http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/14120)
Você cola a assinatura de rotina que deseja chamar, via código gerenciado, e ele monta a construção correspondente que deve ser utilizada.
Outro detalhe importante, para passar strings em chamadas dê preferência por usar a classe StringBuilder, pois ela facilita bastante no caso de liberação de recursos.

Answer (score 0):

A melhor forma de você fazer isso, visto que você tem uma lib é usar uma biblioteca [C++/CLI](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI) no Visual Studio e linkar com sua lib.

Com o C++/CLI você vai poder criar uma DLL que exporta classes *managed* que podem ser usadas sem problema no C#/.net.

É bem mais simples que gerar uma DLL e usar PInvoke.